# Plotly sankey - save changes (node positions) in HTML file

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, r-plotly, plotly-python, plotly.js

I created an interactive sankey diagram with python and Plotly. Since the overview is relatively poor, the nodes have to be re-arranged manually.
Is there a way to save the new positions of the nodes in the html file?

I already tried saving the file via the browser (Chrome and Firefox) but after reopening it the new node positions are gone.

This code will open the browser and it will show the sankey. You will be able to move the nodes - i tried to "save as" but after reopening the saved html file it showes the sankey without the changed node positions.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"],
      color = "blue"
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3], # indices correspond to labels, eg A1, A2, A1, B1, ...
      target = [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5],
      value = [8, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2]
  ))])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Basic Sankey Diagram", font_size=10)
#fig.write_html("test.html")
fig.show()
```

If you will uncomment the following row, it will create the html file automatically but as far as i can tell this has no effect on the behavior.

```
#fig.write_html("test.html")
```

Comment: Can you include a code sample so we can reproduce the behavior you are talking about? A minimally reproducible working example will make it more likely you get an answer to your question too

Comment: let's start with what you tried. What is the first thing you tried and didnt work? show us the code you wrote.